# Why isn't the "user" class found?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a PHP web application with Laravel and am trying to pass a name and email from a form to my database, but it displays this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'user' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\app\controller\home.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\app\core\app.php(43): home->create('hala',
>   'hala@yahoo') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\public\index.php(4):
>   app->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\app\controller\home.php on line 20

This is the code I'm using for the home page:

```
class home extends controller
{    
    public function index($name = '')
    {
        $this->view('home/index', ['name'=>$user->name]);
    }

    public function create($username = '', $email = '')
    {
        user::create([
            'username' => $username,
            'email'=> $email
        ]);
    }
}
```

and the model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class user extends Eloquent 
{
    public $name;
    protected $fillable = ['username','email'];
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the `user` class?

Comment: Your model is referencing Laravel classes, but your other file paths don't look like Laravel ones. Have you tried capitalizing `User`?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller code, you need to include the `user` class:

```
require_once("user.class.php"); /* or whatever the file is named */
```

If this is done automatically and the class is in a different namespace, you need to declare your intent to use it in the controller:

```
use \my\namespace\user;
```

Or just use the fully qualified class name in your code:

```
\my\namespace\user::create();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `illuminate/database` then chances are you are using composer. Why not add a PSR-4 auto load rule and structure your code accordingly. Eg. `composer.json` might look like this:

```
{
    "name": "acme/acme",
    "description": "Acme is this and that",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "src"
      }
    },
    "license": "proprietary"
}
```

Runing `composer install` makes you an `vendor/autoloader.php` and it is the only file you need to require.  You put your own code un the `Acme` (or whatever you chose) namespace. Eg. You put your user model under `src/Model/User.php` and add your namespace:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public $name;
    protected $fillable = ['username','email'];
}
```

Your main file might look like this..

```
<?php 
// entry point file

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Acme\Model\User;
$user = new User();
// ...
```

Obviously you would make most logic in some class so this should be quite short.

This might seem obvious to people working on recent projects, but I have seen too many projects that still have a static file including all the classes like we did in the olden days. Move your projects to the 2010s now!